# Unable to connect SIP client with Asterisk

Tags: ubuntu, asterisk, sip, pbx, 3cx

I am unable to connect 3CX softphone with Asterisk running on Ubuntu. It is showing the error saying: 
"Rejecting '10.42.0.13' due to a failure to pass ACL '(BASELINE)'"
I have successfully created the account for users in the SIP.conf. 
Please help me with this.

Answer (score -2):

You need translate error.

Error cleary say that you have change you extension ACL, otherwise it will not work.